# Build Project From Terminal throws Provisioning Profile error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, terminal

I am trying to create `ipa` of my `application` using `terminal`.

I am able to successfully `build` my application, but when converting into an `ipa`, it throws the following error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Certificate/xxxx.mobileprovision”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

When I try to build the same application using `X-Code`, it works fine with the same `provisioning profile`.

The script I am running to build the `ipa` is

```
xcodebuild -verbose -project Build_Project_From_Terminal.xcodeproj -scheme nameOfProject -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos clean archive CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx/Project Name/build" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/Certificate/xxxxx.mobileprovision"
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have changed my script to

```
DEVELOPER_NAME="xxxxxxxxx" APP_NAME="xxxxxx"

xcodebuild archive -project $APP_NAME.xcodeproj -scheme $APP_NAME -archivePath ./$APP_NAME.xcarchive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat APP -archivePath ./$APP_NAME.xcarchive -exportPath ./$APP_NAME.ipa

iphoneos PackageApplication -v ./$APP_NAME.app -o ./$APP_NAME.ipa --sign $DEVELOPER_NAME --embed ./*.mobileprovision
```

With this I am getting `$APP_NAME.ipa.app` as output. When I try to install this, it does not install at all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please use an alternate method. This is a working example

---

DEVELOPER_NAME="Your apple developer name"
APP_NAME="application name"

xcodebuild archive -workspace $APP_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme $APP_NAME -archivePath ./$APP_NAME.xcarchive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat APP -archivePath ./$APP_NAME.xcarchive -exportPath ./$APP_NAME.ipa

iphoneos PackageApplication -v ./$APP_NAME.app -o ./$APP_NAME.ipa --sign $DEVELOPER_NAME --embed ./*.mobileprovision

---

Save above shell script in a file (abc.sh) and save that file in your project folder along with your provision profile. Run this script using terminal will save ipa in the project directory.

Comment: Are you sure used provision profile will work for the device id you tested ?

For testing that please do the following steps...

------------
1. rename *.ipa - *.zip
2. unarchive *.zip - Open Paylod directory - Show Package Contents of "ApplicationName" - Open 'embed.provision' file in text editor
3. Search for your device UDID in that file
4. If the UDID does not appear in embed.provision please use a valid provison profile

Comment: What string you replace for 'APP_NAME' ?